# Laravel: Methods of long term storage

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am just diving into Laravel and on the 64th page of the official manual "Code Bright" by Dayle Rees he states:

> **Database**
>
> Should you choose to use a database as a method of long term
>   storage, then this directory will be used to hold the files that will
>   create your database schema, and methods for seeding it with sample
>   data. The default SQLite database is also located in this directory.

Of course the question that comes up to me is, are there any other methods of "long term storage" I should be aware of?

I thought till now that databases are the way to go... but is there something completely out of my radar?

Comment: This should not really be a question on here but a good one on the laravel forum or even to Dayle Rees himself (sorry Dayle).

Long term basically means that the data contained within is going to be access/used of a long period of time like BLogs, Website details, Store content etc 

If you are using a db for things such as keeping details alive as long as a page is etc then look into other methods such as local storage / cache etc 

I am sure there is more to this

Comment: Right. I totally forgot, that he could have meant something inferior to databases in terms of technological advancement, like files, cache or similar methods.